# Update table based on currentYear value from dropdown (external data)

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a table displaying vacation requests from employees. Right now I'm displaying requests from all years in that table with the "onAttach" event. I want to implement a dropdown with a binding to the "year" column in my external sql data. so whenever I select a year out of that dropdown, I want the table to update only showing requests from that specific year in the table. How do I implement it?

the onAttach function `loadHolidayTable()` of the table leads to this client function

```
function loadHolidayTable() {
  app.datasources.HolidayModel.load({
    failure: function (error) {
      displayTimedSnackbar('Unable to load holidays table: ' + error);
    }
  });
}
```

My Server Script in the datasource "HolidayModel"

```
return calculateHolidayModel(query);
```

leads to this server function:

```
function calculateHolidayModel(query) {
  var queryStr = '';
  var currentYear = null; --> to be replaced by dropdown value

  if (currentYear === null || currentYear == 'undefined') {
    queryStr = 'SELECT * FROM Holidays WHERE employeeID = ' + "'" + empID + "'";
  }
  else {
    queryStr = 'SELECT * FROM Holidays WHERE employeeID = ' + "'" + empID + "'" + ' AND year = ' + "'" + currentYear + "'";
  }

  console.log(queryStr);

  //var dayRecords = [];
  var holidayRecords = [];
  var connection = getJDBCConnection_();
  var statement = connection.prepareStatement(queryStr);

  try {
    var results = statement.executeQuery();

    while(results.next()) {
      var holidayRecord = app.models.HolidayModel.newRecord();
      holidayRecord.ID = results.getInt(2);
      holidayRecord.From = new Date(results.getString(3));
      holidayRecord.To = new Date(results.getString(4));
      holidayRecord.Status = results.getString(5);
      holidayRecords.push(holidayRecord);
      console.log(results.getInt(2));
    }
    results.close();
    statement.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

  return holidayRecords;
}
```

`currentYear` should be replaced by the value from the dropdown.

any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Can you tell us if your current code is working or throwing any errors?

Comment: @MarkusMalessa the current code works and lists all holiday requests, I'm having trouble implementing the year filter in the dropdown

Comment: Add currentYear as a number type parameter to your calculated datasource. Bind your dropdown to `@datasource.query.parameters.currentYear`. Replace your `var currentYear = null;` with `var currentYear = query.parameters.currentYear`. That should do it. Let me know if it doesn't work. Also replace 'undefined' with just undefined, undefined is not a string type.

Comment: @MarkusMalessa for some reason I can't bind the dropdown to ```@datasources.HolidayModel.query.parameters.currentYear``` although its available in "choose a binding". It's just grey'd out for some reason

Comment: How are your options generated, is it like [2016,2017,2018] or are they generated otherwise? If you set your options before the value, then the value binding can have some dependency on how you set your options, like a type mismatch.

Comment: @MarkusMalessa the options should be generated throught a year column in the external "Holidays" table. It's the same table that all the other data comes from

Comment: So how are you accomplishing this though? Do you have a binding on your drop down options? I would suggest starting with a new dropdown, bind the value to your datasource parameter currentYear and in the options literally put in [2019,2018,2017] just to make sure that it works. Sometimes widgets seem to get ‘broken’ and certain bindings that should be available are greyed out.

Comment: @MarkusMalessa I implemented it and it works. Now all I need is the table to update whenever a year is selected. How do I delete the records in the datasource or override it with the records from just the selected year? ```app.datasources.HolidayModel.unload();```doesn't do the trick

Comment: You need to include app.datasources.HolidayModel.load() in your dropdown onValueEdit event.

Comment: I included it, added a client function which passes currentYear to the server function, but when I try to use ```function calculateHolidayModel(query, currentYear)``` on the server function now, ```currentYear``` is not working properly

Comment: @MarkusMalessa cause in the Server Script of the datasource I already defined the function ```return calculateHolidayModel(query);```with the query as a parameter and now I'm trying to call it again but with the query + the currentYear parameter

Comment: You don’t need to include a client function to pass the currentYear to the server function. Since you have a datasource Parameter for it and the binding it will automatically get passed in the query object when you reload the datasource.

Comment: Alright I almost got it all implemented (it reloads the datasource correctly), but how do I access the datasource Parameter in the server function correctly? the ```console.log(currentYear)```afterwards always returns undefined

Comment: @MarkusMalessa ```query.parameters.currentYear```did the trick. Now everything is working as intended. Thank you very much for your time and help!